# Can I export server name as column value into a flat file destination?

Tags: parameters, ssis, substring, flatfiledestination

I have a parameterized OLE DB Source connection manager in SSIS. From that I want to retrieve just the server name and print it as a row in a flat file destination.

The connection manager is something like

```
"Data Source=TESTSERVER.local;Initial Catalog=TEST_DB;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;"
```

From this I want to retrieve just `TESTSERVER.local` and use it as a column value. Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: If you want the server name you could select SELECT @@SERVERNAME as part of your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have access to that parameter for the whole connection string.

Try using TOKEN twice in a derived column.

```
TOKEN(TOKEN(Parameter, ";",1), "=",2)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/token-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15